# Calculating <article> Height Based on the Number of its Container children()

Tags: jquery, html, css

What I am trying to achieve here is to calculate the width and height of each child based on its number of its number of its container children().

Width = container width / number of its children
Height = Width (or) Width*0.75 (or) Width*0.5625  'based on if conditions

Here is my code **always returns height = tileHeightSquare**

Any Ideas??

```
<style>
.container {
background-color:#FFF;
display:table;
box-sizing:border-box;
width:100%;
}
.tile {
 background-color:silver;
 display:table-cell;
 vertical-align:middle;
 text-align:center;
 -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 0 3px #FFF;
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3px #FFF;
 box-shadow:         inset 0 0 0 3px #FFF;  
 }
 </style>

<HTML>
<main class="container">
    <article class="tile">
        <h1>A1</h1>
    </article>

    <article class="tile">
        <h1>A2</h1>
    </article>
</main>

<main class="container">
    <article class="tile">
        <h1>B1</h1>
    </article>
    <article class="tile">
        <h1>B2</h1>
    </article>
    <article class="tile">
        <h1>B3</h1>
    </article>
</main>

<main class="container"></main>

</HTML>




<script>
function flexTiles() {
    $('.container').each(function() {
        var noOfTiles = $(this).children().length; //no of tiles in each container
        var containerWidth = $(this).innerWidth(); //main container width
        var tileWidth = (containerWidth / noOfTiles);
        var tileHeightBox = tileWidth;
        var tileHeightSquare = tileWidth * 0.75;
        var tileHeightWide = tileWidth * 0.5625;
        if (noOFTiles = 1) {
            $(this).children().css({
                'width': tileWidth + 'px',
                'height': tileHeightWide + 'px'
            });
        }
        if (noOFTiles = 2) {
            $(this).children().css({
                'width': tileWidth + 'px',
                'height': tileHeightSquare + 'px'
            });
        } else {
            $(this).children().css({
                'width': tileWidth + 'px',
                'height': tileHeightBox + 'px'
            });
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: please find the HTML included above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your `if` statements aren't checking the value of `noOfTiles`, they are setting it because you are using a singl'e `=`, which always causes the expression to evaluate to `true`:

```
 if (noOFTiles = 1) {
```

Change that to the comparison operator:

```
 if (noOFTiles == 1) {
```

Or, better yet, if no type coercion is necessary:

```
 if (noOFTiles === 1) {
```

**Second, you are incorrectly accessing `noOfTiles`, by testing `noOFTiles`.**

Third, you are using two, separate `if` statements, so each statement will run and since the second one sets `'height': tileHeightSquare + "px"`, that's the one that you end up with.

You need to modify the two statements into one, like this:

```
    if (noOfTiles == 1) {
        $(this).children().css({
            'width': tileWidth + 'px',
            'height': tileHeightWide + 'px'
        });
    } else if (noOfTiles == 2) {
        $(this).children().css({
            'width': tileWidth + 'px',
            'height': tileHeightSquare + 'px'
        });
    } else {
        $(this).children().css({
            'width': tileWidth + 'px',
            'height': tileHeightBox + 'px'
        });
    }
```

Also, just for a better design, follow the best practice of DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself), which makes for a slimmer code-base, easier scaling and less prone to bugs:

```
    var h = tileHeightBox;

    if (noOfTiles == 1) {
            h = tileHeightWide;
    } else if (noOfTiles == 2) {
            h = tileHeightSquare;
    }

    $(this).children().css({
        'width': tileWidth + 'px',
        'height': h + 'px'
    });
```

And finally, there should really only be one `main` element in a page to keep the purpose of the semantics correct. You may want to use `section`, as I've shown below, instead:

```js
$(flexTiles);

function flexTiles() {
    $('.container').each(function() {
      
        var noOfTiles = $(this).children().length; //no of tiles in each container   
        var containerWidth = $(this).innerWidth(); //main container width     
        var tileWidth = (containerWidth / noOfTiles);    
        var tileHeightBox = tileWidth;     
        var tileHeightSquare = tileWidth * 0.75;     
        var tileHeightWide = tileWidth * 0.5625;     
      
        var h = tileHeightBox;     

        //  >>>>  You had: noOFTiles, instead of noOfTiles  <<<<
        if(noOfTiles == 1) {
            h = tileHeightWide;
        } else if(noOfTiles == 2) {
            h = tileHeightSquare;           
        }


        $(this).children().css({
          'width': tileWidth + 'px',
          'height': h + 'px'
        });
    });
}
```

```css
<style>
.container {
background-color:#FFF;
display:table;
box-sizing:border-box;
width:100%;
}
.tile {
 background-color:silver;
 display:table-cell;
 vertical-align:middle;
 text-align:center;
 -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 0 3px #FFF;
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3px #FFF;
 box-shadow:         inset 0 0 0 3px #FFF;  
 }
 </style>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="container">
    <article class="tile">
        <h1>A1</h1>
    </article>

    <article class="tile">
        <h1>A2</h1>
    </article>
</section>

<section class="container">
    <article class="tile">
        <h1>B1</h1>
    </article>
    <article class="tile">
        <h1>B2</h1>
    </article>
    <article class="tile">
        <h1>B3</h1>
    </article>
</section>

<section class="container"></section>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, when I change the comparison operator neither style is added :(

Comment: @Mazen See my updated answer about your multiple `if` statements.

Comment: thank yo again for the cleaner code, but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: when I use the correct logical operator "==" the css style doesn't apply at all. When i use just "=" it applies the tileHeightSquare for all <articles> in the document

Comment: @Mazen Your final issue was incorrectly capitalizing the `noOfTiles` variable. My above code snippet now works.

Answer (score 1):

As Scott mentioned in his response, the reason your code was failing was because wrong syntax in the if-else statements. However I think it's worth nothing this function could be better written by not repeating so much of it.

What I mean is you should avoid try to repeat code as much as possible, and keep the code DRY (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

In your code you might apply the DRY-principle like this:

```
function flexTiles() {
    $('.container').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this), // cache the dom-element
            noOfTiles = $this.children().length,
            containerWidth = $this.innerWidth(),
            tileWidth = (containerWidth / noOfTiles),
            tileHeightBox = tileWidth, // I dont mind this redeclaring
            tileHeightSquare = tileHeightBox * 0.75, // But for readability you should use tileHeightBox here instead of tileWidth
            tileHeightWide = tileHeightBox * 0.5625,
            thisTileHeight;

        // I assume the only outcome of noOfTiles is 1, 2 or 3. So I would rather use a switch/case
        switch(noOfTiles) {
             case 1:
                 thisTileHeight = tileHeightWide;
                 break;

             case 2:
                 thisTileHeight = tileHeightSquare;
                 break;

             case 3:
                 thisTileHeight = tileHeightBox;
                 break;
        }

        // Then change the css
        $this.children().css({
            'width': tileWidth + 'px',
            'height': thisTileHeight + 'px'
        });
    });
}
```

As you can see, cleaner code, and much more readable :)

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2o4bdp3c/1/